# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.version.InvalidVersionSpecificationException

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, aether

I am using the maven indexer to fetch the maven index from the maven central repository. Since I updated from org.sonatype.aether to org.eclipse.aether and from maven 3.0.5 to maven 3.1.0 I am getting this Exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.version.InvalidVersionSpecificationException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
```

Maven tells me that I should check out this page: http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound. Did that. But on the page they just say that they are aware of this problem and they updated some maven plugins to run with maven 3.1.0. But they don't say what is the problem and how to solve it. That is not very useful. 
What I have to change to make my own plugin work with maven 3.1.0 ???

I double checked my dependencies with:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

And it seems that the old org.sonatype.aether.aether-api.jar is still in the project, which contains the Exception. So basically the org.sonatype.aether.version.InvalidVersionSpecificationException is part of my project. So why do I get this Exception ??

Answer (score 29):

Use a later version of maven-dependency-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    .... your configuration here ....
</plugin>
```

Comment: This did not work for me -- problem can occur with 2.8. But in my case, upgrading maven-shade-plugin from 2.0 to 2.1 did the trick. Why? I've no clue. But somehow that worked around the issue.

Comment: @Nico Somehow that doesn't solve the problem for me. I enforced version 2.8 of maven-dependency-plugin and version 2.1 of the maven-shade-plugin. Did a mvn clean install, but still the same error.

Comment: Worked for me: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree` since I was using command-line

Comment: upgrade from 2.5 to 2.8 solved my problem.

Comment: @acdcjunior Thanks, your comment is the actual answer

Answer (score 11):

This error is caused by the Maven 3.1-alpha-1 migration from Sonatype Aether to Eclipse Aether, which is an incompatible change for some plugins.

To support this change, new versions of the affected plugins have been published which work both with Maven 3.0.x and 3.1.x. A list of affected plug-ins and their minimum needed version is available at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound

Comment: I just wonder why the did not bump up the major version number, if it is a breaking change. People should care more about semantic versioning.

Comment: In simple terms, you recommend running with maven `3.2.5` instead of `3.0.5` (which is for example bundled with intellij)

Answer (score 4):

Converting my previous comment into an answer, you can use:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree
```

Naturally, you can [specify any version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin).