# Jenkins fails due to NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/version/VersionConstraint

Tags: jenkins, noclassdeffounderror, sonatype

I'm attempting to set up Jenkins on my server but after building the job things turn south. You can view the console here: http://ci.lolmewn.nl/job/AcceptRules/4/console

At first I thought this was an issue with me not having configured my nexus yet (since the error contained sonatype, the makers of Nexus), but when I built one of my jobs without it having repository pushing, this still happened.

Any clues? I see there's a question like mine, unanswered however, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169415/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-sonatype-aether-version-invalidversionspec)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the Maven explanation for it. This might be your error.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound